# How to find the page views in the SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-online, graph-api

How to find the page views in the SharePoint? Here in the attachment the count is 1030. How to get for all the pages in the SharePoint site with API.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below search api to get page views count:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='path:https://{domian}.sharepoint.com/sites/{sitename}/SitePages/{pagename}.aspx'&selectproperties='Title,path,ViewsLifeTime,ViewsLifeTimeUniqueUsers'
```

[image]

[image]

This site goes into pretty good detail of using the search api:

- [SharePoint Search REST API overview](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/sharepoint-search-rest-api-overview)